# Cant get form data on a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

im trying to get the params of my post request. I can send them with JSON and it will work (if i take out the type property of the BodyParser.json) but not form data. Im using the body-parser middleware as follows.

```
const BodyParser      = require('body-parser')

const Config          = require('../config/environment');

const Express         = require("express");
const App             = Express();

App.use(BodyParser.json({type: '/', limit: '50mb'}));
App.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

App.listen(3000, () => {Response.logger('Api running on port 3000.');});  

App.post("/signup", (req, res, next) =>
{
    consoleAlert('SIGNUP', false);

    console.log(req);

    Account.signup(req.params).then(
    function(results) {response(results, res, 'SIGNUP');},
    function(error)   {response(error, res, 'SIGNUP');});
});
```

So when i print out req, the body is always empty with form data

Comment: Try to set `extended: true`

Comment: That didnt work, Im starting to think Body-parser doesnt actually support form data

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code, the fault must be on client (browser) side.

Comment: How are you sending the HTTP request? What does the Content-Type *request* header say? What does the request body look like? You need to provide an [mcve] - we can't tell why some code can't parse some data based only on a vague description of the data.

Comment: Im using postman, Sending the parameters through body->form-data. The content type is Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: I have fixed this by switching to Multer instead of Body-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written from scratch - this appears to work:

server:

```
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3022);
```

client: call curl from command line sending form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the default), mine node server IP is 10.10.1.40 :

```sh
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST http://10.10.1.40:3022/
```